# Scrollbar of DIV with position FIXED is partly hidden behind window scrollbar

Tags: css, scrollbar, fixed

I have a table of contents in my page (see [here](http://www.pdark.de/haul/SceneFile-f446bc18-fdbc-42dd-bfde-2f501e2e7f73.html)) with these CSS styles:

```
div.toc {
    height:38em;
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    top:5em;
    width:21em;
    z-index:1;
}
```

How do I have to change these settings to make sure the DIV isn't partially hidden behind the body/window scroll bar?

(Tested with Firefox 3.6 and Opera 10.10).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, your `div.toc` is properly positioned. The problem is with your `<iframe>`.

Remember your box model... width and height is calculated independently from the margin and padding...

[image: W3C Box Model]

So, by having `width: 100%;` on your `iframe.toc` plus a `margin-left: 0.5em`, you are basically telling the browser the following:

> Use the full width of the parent element and offset it `0.5em` to the left.
>   **Total effective width: 100% + 0.5em**

What you really want to say is the following:

> Substract `0.5em` from the full width of the parent element to use as padding on the left and use this as width.
>   **Total effective width: 100% - 0.5em** (desired)

The solution is therefore simple... Remove the `margin-left` from `iframe.toc` and put a `padding-left: 0.5em` on `div.toc`.

```
div.toc {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 5em;
    right: 0;
    width: 21em;
    height: 38em;
    padding-left: .5em;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    z-index: 1;
}

iframe.toc {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    border: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make you table of contents position 1 em from the right like this: `right: 1em;`

I just tried it for you and `right: 1em;` looks good.

Comment: It will look odd if there is no window scrollbar :-( Isn't there a way to say "right" == "left border of the window scrollbar"?

Comment: No idea why 1em works exactly, but it does for me. Make sure to check your css on font-size when using this fix.